# Cannont resolve symbol JSONObject (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, json

I have spent two days in this. I can work with other PC, but my Android Studio doesn´t import the library, I took two captures:

As yo can see in the first picture, Android Studio autocompletes my line:

[image: Autocompleted]

However:

[image: ERROR]

I was reading about JSONObject in Android Developers ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)) and Android include this in library. I also have tried to import other libraries from "org", but just works fine two of them:

[image: Problems org]

Them... I was thinking this might be a problem of Android Studio, and I reinstalled the IDE, the error persists.

And I have tried to import the library in the gradle (this is in build.gradle module: app):

[image]

I was working with other PC, it works well, but I need to fix this in my computer.

Please, any help will be grateful.

Comment: I don't see why you got a downvote, indeed `JSONObject` is included with Android and your error is strange.

Comment: Can you also post your 'app/build.gradle' file?

Comment: Try this: `File -> Invalidate caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`. You can try to delete `~/.gradle/caches` directory to force re-download the dependencies, too.

Comment: I was with my boss. I going to try to make all this. My App build.gradle is this (I cant put all code, anyway, the problem is in all projects)

    dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
      compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
    }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I´ll respond to the future, if someone has the same error:

I did this (Thaks to Bigdestroyer):

```
File -> Invalidate caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```

You can try to delete `~/.gradle/caches` directory to force re-download the dependencies.

Now its works perfect. Thanks !!!!