# Cannot resolve symbol getJSONObject in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio

1) The JSONObject library is imported

2) I've added 'org.json:json:2014113' as a dependency in the gradle file.

3) Updated jar files.

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

        JSONObject currently = new forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
```

Android Studio is not recognizing getJSONObject even though it came up as an auto complete suggestion.

The compile error was as follows:

```
 error: package forecast does not exist
```

Solutions tried: 
[Cannont resolve symbol JSONObject (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916334/cannont-resolve-symbol-jsonobject-android-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this particular line:

```
JSONObject currently = new forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
```

You don't need to use `new` to get the JSONObject, the IDE thinks forecast is a type or a package and it can't find it in your project so it's throwing an error, you should change the previous line to this:

```
JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");
```

Hope it helps you, happy coding.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very very new to this :)